# How can I add some vertical spacing to table cells?

Tags: tables

I have a table created with `tabular` but the text seems too close to the top border. Is there a way to add some padding to the table cells?

[image]

```
\begin{tabular}[t]{|l|l|l|l|}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Content Words}\\
        \hline
        NOUNS & person & place & thing\\
        \hline
        VERBS & go & run & think \\
        \hline
        ADJECTIVES & good & bad & right \\
        \hline
        ADVERBS & very & almost & quite \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
```

I would be grateful for any suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: Would https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31672/column-and-row-padding-in-tables help?

Comment: Yes. I added the `\def\arraystretch` to the preamble. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the easiest ways is to load the package `array` and invoke

```
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{<factor>}
```

to increase the default cell spaces in all rows by `factor`.

There are many other alternatives to increase independently the space above and the space below the cells, expand a single row, etc.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.8}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{tabular}[t]{|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Content Words}\\
    \hline
    NOUNS & person & place & thing\\
    \hline
    VERBS & go & run & think \\
    \hline
    ADJECTIVES & good & bad & right \\
    \hline
    ADVERBS & very & almost & quite \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}   

\end{document}
```

Comment: This does not always seem to center the text in the cells.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution, in my opinion, uses the `cellspace` package, which defines tools  for minimal vertical spacing at the top & bottom of cells in columns with specifier prefixed with the letter `S` (or `C` if you load `siunitx`, or any letter you please with the loading time option `column= some letter`).

Here is how it goes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{6pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{6pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}[t]{|Sl|l|l|l|}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{4}{|Sc|}{Content Words}\\
        \hline
        NOUNS & person & place & thing\\
        \hline
        VERBS & go & run & think \\
        \hline
        ADJECTIVES & good & bad & right \\
        \hline
        ADVERBS & very & almost & quite \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Beware: `\hspace` is ignored in cells when using this package